# Jquery Datepicker month icon don't show in IE10+

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-10, jquery-ui-datepicker, internet-explorer-11

Everything working fine on Chrome and IE 9, but on IE10 and higher month arrow don't show anyone have encounter this bug ?

[image: IE10+]

Thanks for you help.

Comment: can you inspect the element, check if it's the CSS, or maybe the image isn't even being found?

Comment: I just tried one of my datepicker applications and it works fine in IE10 at BrowserStack.com.

Comment: Images wasn't found because of right... everything fixed now! Thanks